# column cannot be NULL while inserting in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

I am trying to retrieve roleid from pr_users which matches username column from the same table. The username field is actually the email address of that particular user. There are 2 functions, one is function add_new_checklist and the other is function get_roleid, i am passing  the $dbdata['responsibility'] from the else part to the function get_roleid. I want to retrieve userroleid from pr_users which matches the username column in the variable $dbdata['responsibility']. I am calling function get_roleid from the else part
i.e $role_id = $this->get_roleid($var); and also attached table image.

But i am getting an error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'roleid' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO pr_exit_checklists (`action_item`, `category`,
>   `responsibility`, `target_completion_period`, `target_completion_day`,
>   `target_completion_from`, `status`, `roleid`) VALUES ('new item',
>   'Administration', 'shashankbhat11@gmail.com', 'after', '5',
>   'Resignation Date', '1', NULL)

My Model code is;

```html
   function add_new_checklist($post_array,$action)
{       


      global $USER;
   $post_arr = $this->input->post();
   

   
   global $USER;
   $dbdata = array();
   $fn = 'insert';
     
   $dbdata['action_item'] = $post_array['actions'];
   $dbdata['category'] = $post_array['departmentname'];
  
   if($post_array['responsibility2'] == 'individual')
   {
    $dbdata['responsibility'] = 'Individual';
    
   }
    else if($post_array['responsibility2'] == 'supervisor'){
   $dbdata['responsibility'] = 'supervisor';
   }
   else{
   $dbdata['responsibility'] = $post_array['responsibility'];
    $var = $dbdata['responsibility'];
   $role_id = $this->get_roleid($var);
   }
   $dbdata['target_completion_period'] = $post_array['target_completion_period'];
   $dbdata['target_completion_day'] = $post_array['target_completion_day'];
   $dbdata['target_completion_from'] = $post_array['target_completion_from'];
   $dbdata['status'] = '1';
   $dbdata['roleid'] = $role_id;
   
   /*$dbdata['opening_date'] = date("Y-m-d");*/
   $characters = array(
   "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","J","K","L","M",
   "N","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
   "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");

   //make an "empty container" or array for our keys
   $keys = array();

   //first count of $keys is empty so "1", remaining count is 1-7 = total 8 times
   while(count($keys) < 8) {
    //"0" because we use this to FIND ARRAY KEYS which has a 0 value
    //"-1" because were only concerned of number of keys which is 32 not 33
    //count($characters) = 33
    $x = mt_rand(0, count($characters)-1);
    if(!in_array($x, $keys)) {
       $keys[] = $x;
    }
   

   foreach($keys as $key){
      $random_chars .= $characters[$key];
   }
   //$dbdata['ref_no'] =  $random_chars;
   
   $fn = ($action=='inserted')?'insert':'update'; 
   if($fn == 'update' )
   {
    
    $this->db->where("id",$post_array['id']);
    $this->db->$fn('pr_exit_checklists',$dbdata);
    return 'Resignation Request updated successfully'; 
   }
   
   if($fn == 'insert' ) { 
    if($this->db->$fn('pr_exit_checklists',$dbdata)){
     $instanceid = ($fn=='insert')?$this->db->insert_id():$post_array['id'];
     
     if($fn=='insert')
     {
       global $USER;
       $fullname = $this->get_name_by_username($USER->username);
       
       
     }
     global $USER;
   $post_arr = $this->input->post();
   
   $manager_id = $this->get_value_by_id('managerid','users',$this->session->userdata('admin_id'));
   $user_id='1';
     $v_memberid = $manager_id . "," . $user_id;
      //$manager_id = $this->get_value_by_id('managerid','users',$this->session->userdata('admin_id'));
     $notification_data['ref_table']   = 'pr_resignation_requests'; 
     $notification_data['ref_id']   = $instanceid;
     $notification_data['modifier_id']  = $USER->id;
     $notification_data['show_users']  = $v_memberid;
     $notification_data['notification_descr']= "Resignation Request Received" ;//$manager_id;
     $notification_data['notification_text'] = "Resignation Request Received";
     $notification_data['added_on']   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
     $notification_data['url']    = 'exits';
     $notification_data['uurl']    = 'exits';
     $this->db->insert($this->myTables['notifications'],$notification_data);
     return 'Exit Checklist Added Success';
    
    
    $message_body = "Dear Manager,<br><br> A resignation request is being recieved. <br><br>Please find the details below : <br><br>
    Name: ".$rqrow->firstname.' '.$rqrow->lastname."<br><br>
    Email: ".$rqrow->email." <br><br>
    Phone: ".$rqrow->phone_number." <br><br>
    
    
    Please login to the portal <a href='".base_url()."'>".base_url()."</a> to view the complete status of your resource requisitions. <br><br>
    
    <br><br>
    Yours sincerely,<br>
    Admin<br>
       Mappsit<br>";
    
    $to   = $this->get_email_by_id($manager_id);// email id of the recipient
      
    $subject = "Dear Manager. You have recieved a resignation request";
    $headers = "From: info@mappsit.com\r\n";
    $headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    //$headers.= "CC: ".$cc_email_id."\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
    
    
    


     
    }
   }
   return false;
        }

   

    
}


   function get_roleid($var)
   {
    
      
  $sql = "SELECT userroleid FROM `pr_users` WHERE `username` LIKE '%".$var."%'";
  $query=$this->db->query($sql); 
  if($query->num_rows() > 0){
   $result=$query->result();
  }
  return;


}
```

Controller code:

```html
 function add_new_checklist()
  {

    
    
       global $SITE,$USER;
   $data = array();
   $data['row'] = new stdClass();
   $data['row'] = $this->admin_init_elements->set_post_vals($this->input->post());
   $data['offices']=$this->mod_common->get_all_offices();
   $clients = currentuserclients();
   $data['roles'] = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array('designation','status',"1' AND id > '0",'designation');
   
    $data['reasons'] = $this->exit_common->get_all_reasons();
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
   
  

   
   
   //$data['roles'] = $this->exit_common->get_cat_array('designation','status',"1' AND id > '0",'designation');
   get_city_state_country_array($data,array('cityid'=>$data['row']->cityid));
   $data['error_message'] = '';
   $data['row']->id = $this->uri->segment(3);
   $data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);   
   $data['action'] = 'add';
   $data['heading'] = 'Add';   
   $data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
   $data['path']=$path;  
   $post_action = $this->input->post('action');
   if($post_action=='add' || $post_action =='update' ){
    $post_array = $this->input->post();
    $action = ($post_action == 'add')?'inserted':'updated';
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($SITE);die;
     $post_array['exit_type'] = 'Employee Initiated';
     $data['managerid'] = $this->exit_common->get_managerids($id);
     $data['error_message'] = $this->exit_common->add_new_checklist($post_array,$action);
     
       
     if($data['error_message'] == 'Record '.$action.' successfully'){
      $data['row'] = new stdClass();
      $data['row']->id = $this->uri->segment(3); 
      $data['row']->status = 1;
      
     }
    
   }
   $data['grievance_types'] = $this->mod_common->get_user_allowed_leaves();
   if($data['row']->id>0){
    $data['action'] = 'update';
    $data['heading'] = 'Edit';
    $data['rows'] = $this->mod_common->get_leave_request($data['row']->id);
    $clid = $data['row']->id; 
    $data['row']->id = $clid;
   }
   //$data['my_detail'] = $this->mod_common->get_my_details($USER->id);
   $data['my_detail'] = $this->exit_common->get_details_profile($USER->id,'users_details','userid'); 
   $data['my_detail']->userdetail = $this->exit_common->get_details($USER->id,'users');
   get_address($data['my_detail'],ADDRESS_TYPE1,$USER->id);
   $data['cities']=$this->exit_common->get_array_frontend('city');
    $data['category'] = $this->exit_common->get_departments_as_category();
   $data['roles'] = $this->exit_common->get_roles();
    $data['emailid'] = $this->exit_common->get_emailid();
   
   $this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/display_form_for_adding_checklist', $data,true); 
   $this->load->view('layout', $this->data);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
   
  }
```

view code:

```html
             <div class="col-md-5 pull-right">
                            <div class="control-group form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                   Responsiblity Of
         <span class="req_star">*</span>
                                </label>

                                <div class="controls">
                                   <?php 
            $options = array();
            $options['individual']='Individual';
            $options['supervisor']='Supervisor';
            $options['function']='others';
            echo form_dropdown('responsibility2', $options, explode(",",$row->role),'id="resp_type" class="form-control function col-md-12 select2" reqired="required" ');
           ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
     </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <?php if($row->resp_type == 'function') $style="style='display:block'"; else $style="style='display:none;'"; ?>
      <div class="row-fluid rowspace resp_dept" <?php echo $style; ?>>
       <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="control-group form-group">
                    

                                <div class="controls">
         <div class="col-md-9">
             <select name="responsibility" class="form-control">
            <?php 

            foreach($emailid as $row)
            { 
 
              echo '<option value="'.$row->username.'">'.$row->username.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
          </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

pr_users table

[image]

pr_exit_checklists table
[image]

Comment: How does the username relate to the responsibility - usernames seem to be email addresses whereas responsibilities appear to be things like Individual & supervisor.

Comment: checklist is related both to responsibility and username and by storing roleid from username i will be able to retieve the email address for mailing puposes in some other steps which i have not disclosed

Comment: my only concern is that i am not able to retrieve the correct userroleid from the table where username = dbdata[''] ... in this code $var = $dbdata['responsibility'];
   $role_id = $this->get_roleid($var); That is my concern

Comment: You are passing the responsibility (individual, supervisor, etc) into the get_roleid function & using it in a query to match against the username which all appear to be email addresses so you are always getting null returned. Without seeing the full tables - there appear to be columns missing from your pictures - then it is very difficult to advise you. Reformatting your code so it can be better seen would be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowing NULL insertion in pr_exit_checklists table and from your query you are trying to insert NULL.
Either you need to enable allow NULL option in table
or You need to change your insert statement and pass roleid as 0 or 1.

Comment: i am not able to retrieve the correct roleid from the table ... That is my concern

Comment: function get_roleid($var)
   {
    
      
  $sql = "SELECT userroleid FROM `pr_users` WHERE `username` LIKE '%".$var."%'";
  $query=$this->db->query($sql); 
  if($query->num_rows() > 0){
   $result=$query->result();
  }
  return;


}